# Ruby on rails 4 check_box_tag not showing up in form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, form-for

I'm a RoR newbie trying to create a form. I want to be able to save all of the values from the form and run a search query on my database based on the values before returning an updated view. I'm on rails 4, and created an array of check boxes using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2qwV0B9yfU, but the check boxes won't show up. I can't seem to find a solution by myself, so I was hoping for some help.

This is my form:
[image]

This is my form.html.erb. It's saved in views/homepage/form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@homepage, url: form_path) do |f| %>
    # <%= render 'shared/error_messages_form' %>
      <%= f.label :dname, "Dish Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :d_name %>

      <%= f.label :rname, "Restaurant Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :r_name %>

    <div class="diet">
       <%= f.label :violation_name, "Dietary Restriction0.5" %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "homepage[dietaryviolation_ids][]", nil %>
        <% Dietaryviolation.all.each do |dietaryviolation| %>

            <%= check_box_tag "homepage[dietaryviolation_ids][]", dietaryviolation.id, @homepage.dietaryviolation_ids.include?(dietaryviolation.diet), id: dom_id(dietaryviolation) %>
            <%= label_tag dom_id(dietaryviolation), dietaryviolation.diet %><br>
          <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="food">
       <%= f.label :food_name, "Restaurant Cuisine0.5" %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "homepage[restaurantcuisine_ids][]", nil %>
        <% @restaurantcuisines.each do |restaurantcuisine| %>
            <%= f.check_box "homepage[restaurantcuisine_ids][]", restaurantcuisine.id, @homepage.restaurantcuisine_ids.include?(restaurantcuisine.diet), id: dom_id(restaurantcuisine) %>
            <%= label_tag dom_id(restaurantcuisine), restaurantcuisine.diet %><br>
          <% end %>
    </div>

  <%= f.label "Calories"%>
    <%= form_for :homepage,  url: form_path do |cal| %>     
        <div id="calorie_slider"></div>
        <%= cal.hidden_field :c_min %>
        <%= cal.hidden_field :c_max %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.label "Rating"%>
    <%= form_for :homepage,  url: form_path do |rate| %>
        <div id="rating_slider"></div>
        <%= rate.hidden_field :r_min %>
        <%= rate.hidden_field :r_max %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.label "Price Range"%>
    <%= form_for :homepage,  url: form_path do |price| %>
        <div id="price_slider"></div>
        <%= price.hidden_field :p_min %>
        <%= price.hidden_field :p_max %>
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Filter my shiz!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

The corresponding HTML for the check_box_tag section looks like this:

```html
<div class="diet">
       <label for="homepage_violation_name">Dietary Restriction0.5</label>
       <input type="hidden" name="homepage[dietaryviolation_ids][]" id="homepage_dietaryviolation_ids_" />
</div>

<div class="food">
       <label for="homepage_food_name">Restaurant Cuisine0.5</label>
       <input type="hidden" name="homepage[restaurantcuisine_ids][]" id="homepage_restaurantcuisine_ids_" />
</div>
```

It seems to be missing the check boxes entirely, so I think this is where the error is but I have no idea why it's happening :(

The corresponding controller is homepage_controller.rb

```
  class HomepageController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
        @homepage = Homepage.new
  end

  def form 
    @restaurantcuisines = Restaurantcuisine.select(:cuisine).distinct
    @dietaryviolations = Dietaryviolation.select(:diet).distinct
    @homepage = Homepage.new(homepage_params)
  end

  def filter
  end

  private

  def homepage_params
    params.permit(:d_name, :r_name, :c_min, :c_max, :r_min, :r_max, :p_min, :p_max, { :restaurantcuisine_ids => [] }, { :dietaryviolation_ids => [] } )
  end

end
```

I have created CRUD functions for restaurantscuisine_controller and dietaryviolations_controller, but nothing else.

The homepage model is linked to the dietaryviolation model and the restaurantscuisine model through a has-and-belongs-to-many relation. The relations are brought together in join tables called dietaryviolations_homepages and homepages_restaurantscuisine. I don't have anything else in the models except for the has_and_belongs_to_many line and some validation checks in Homepage

```
class Homepage < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :restaurantcuisine
has_and_belongs_to_many :dietaryviolation

before_save { self.d_name = d_name.downcase } if ':d_name.present?'
before_save { self.r_name = r_name.downcase } if ':r_name.present?'

validates :c_max, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: 5000, greater_than_or_equal_to: :c_min }
validates :c_min, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: :c_max, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

validates :r_max, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: 5, greater_than_or_equal_to: :r_min }
validates :r_min, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: :r_max, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

validates :p_max, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: 50, greater_than_or_equal_to: :p_min }
validates :p_min, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: :p_max, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

validates_associated :restaurantecuisine
validates_associated :dietaryviolation

end
```

My application.scss file has the following lines:

```html
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require bootstrap-slider
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
@import url(http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css)
```

My application.js file has the following lines:

```html
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Any advice would be appreciated! I've tried a bunch of different ways to make the check boxes work, including using collection_check_box but nothing seems to be working out.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead,

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :foo, Foo.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
<% end %>
```

Do replace `:foo` with the appropriate object names. The classes are meant for css which can be ignored.

Also, just a little explanation as to what is going on.

`collection_check_boxes(object, method, value_method, text_method)`

As taken from [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes), so we have the `:foo` object, the method being `Foo.all`, similar to when you do `<% @restaurantcuisines.each do |restaurantcuisine| %>`. Then we have `:id` which is the `value_method` and lastly our `label` uses `text_method` which is `:name`. Do note, of course if your model **does not** have a `:name` column, you obviously cannot use `:name` for your `text_method`.

I would also like to note, in forms whether is it text_area, etc, it will be `input_method :object`.

Comment: I've put :dietaryviolation for :foo, @dietaryviolations for Foo.all, and :diet for :id and :name since there isn't an :id or :name column (only has diet column which is essentially name, and an ingredient column which is the specific ingredient that violates the diet constraint), but it still isn't showing up.

Comment: The `:id` is definitely there. All tables in rails would automatically have an `id` column for sure. Do try adding it in and see if it works.